# is separating views ( mobile - desktop - tablet ) in laravel 5.4 using jenssegers user agent a good practice

Tags: php, laravel, view, user-agent

Well, guys, currently I am working on a site and I am just wondering if separating views based on user agent is a good practice. 
An example :

> if it is mobile, return the mobile view

So I am just wondering if this a good practice? 
and if there's a down side effect of it. 
Thanks .

Comment: If you're design isn't responsive, this is what you'd pretty  much have to do to have mobile compatibility...

Comment: yeah i know but i am just afraid of any down side

Comment: The downside is you'd have to keep the user agent list up to date.  Otherwise, you'd need some sort of Javascript to check the view port size and send that information to Laravel.  It's usually much easier to just leave the mobile compatibility to the front end.

Comment: my folder structure : 
desktop

Answer (score 0):

I've worked with MongoDB and Jenssegers in Laravel 5.4, and I think the ideal way to handle this is to serve your Laravel back-end as an API service